# is my database password exposed when I connect using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords

I just started reading up on PHP with mySQL, and I am just on the first page (http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php.htm) and it says that I connect to my database within my PHP code by supplying my username and password.

*My question is, would this not leave my password exposed for anyone to then access my database?*

Now I have not learned yet if this connection code is written in a separate php file, or in php inbedded into my html code, but aren't all my files (php, css, js), all available anyways; otherwise how would people's browsers be able to see the results?

Thanks,
-Adrian

Comment: You shouldn't be using this tutorial, it uses the deprecated mysql_* deprecated function. You should find a tutorial on using mysqli or pdo instead.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. If anyone has a favorite place let me know.

Comment: @Adrian IMO, you're much better off starting with something like Laravel - a modern framework that'll teach you modern best practices, including a pretty handy database ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PHP is processed on the server-side, and is never sent (insecure application not withstanding) to the browser. You might also check out [CodeAcademy's](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php) PHP track. I think that would probably be a better guide for you!

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized this, I can be a bit dumb like that sometimes. I have already completed CodeAcademy's PHP lesson. I find CodeAcademy is great for teaching the fundamentals of a language, but does not give information on the application of what you have learned. For example I completed web fundamentals, and knew how to use html and css, but learning how to actualy put up a website, upload files, link my html to my css, took me a full day of reading using other sources I found on google.

Comment: Oh I just realized that you thought I meant that I was reading up on PHP for the first time. I meant that I was reading up on combining mySQL with PHP for the first time. I am also separately learning SQL on http://sqlzoo.net

Answer (score 0):

Php is [server side language](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp). It runs on your server so it wont be visible. (Unless you use any echo's or print ) :D